# How to remove node id and extension from url in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

right now I am working on a project, where I have to show a header navigation with url picker data type, for that I took two fields: Text(Text String) & Link(Url Picker).

To get this navigation link this I have done following code:

Default.aspx

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptMainNavListing" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMainNavListing_OnItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <div class="header_top_links_right">
                        <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlLink" runat="server">
                        </asp:HyperLink>
                        <asp:Literal ID="ltText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                         </div>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Reshape.Framework;
using Reshape.Framework.UI;
using Reshape.Framework.Constants;
using umbraco.NodeFactory;

namespace Reshape.UserControls {
    public partial class Header : BaseLayout {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (!IsPostBack) {
                Node currentNode = Common.GetMainNavigationFolder();
                var childList = currentNode.Children;
                rptMainNavListing.DataSource = currentNode.Children;
                rptMainNavListing.DataBind();
        }
        }

        protected void rptMainNavListing_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
                Node itm = e.Item.DataItem as Node;
                if (itm != null) {
                    Literal ltText = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltText");
                    HyperLink hlLink = e.Item.FindControl("hlLink") as HyperLink;
                    if (ltText != null) {
                        ltText.Text = itm.GetProperty("text").Value;
                    }
                    if (hlLink != null) {
                        hlLink.NavigateUrl = itm.Url;
                        hlLink.Text = itm.GetProperty("link").Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After debugging this code I got url in following form(with id & extension)

```
False1154/regions.aspxRegions 
here id =False1154
extension =regions.aspx
```

I want url only like "Regions".

Answer (score 0):

In web.config, set the umbracoUseDirectoryUrls value to true.

There is some - rather outdated though - documentation here: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/setting-up-umbraco-for-friendly-urls

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered. If you have more questions, please create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to following code....and you will get rid to this problem :-)

```
if (childList.Count > 0) {
                    rptMainNavListing.DataSource = childList; ;
                    rptMainNavListing.DataBind();

                }
```

Repeater Code

```
  protected void rptMainNavListing_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
                Node itm = e.Item.DataItem as Node;
                if (itm != null) {
                    Literal ltText = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltText");
                    HyperLink hlLink = e.Item.FindControl("hlLink") as HyperLink;
                    if (itm.GetProperty(FieldName.LINK) != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(itm.GetProperty(FieldName.LINK).Value)) {
                        hlLink.NavigateUrl = umbraco.library.NiceUrl(Convert.ToInt16(itm.GetProperty(FieldName.LINK).Value));
                    }
                    hlLink.Text = itm.GetProperty(FieldName.TEXT).Value;
                }
            }
        }
```